# What will a foreigner need to legally work as a freelancer (web developer) in France?

Tags: france

What is needed to work legally in France as a freelancer for a foreigner?, I'm specially interested in knowing what is needed when the person is not from the European union, the US, or countries in the Schengen area.

Comment: Are you a freelancer or a remote worker?

Comment: If you are going to physically work in France this website will probably help you best: https://www.expatica.com/fr/employment/employment-law/work-in-france-guide-to-french-work-visas-and-permits-101098/ You could also ask legal experts here: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are legally present in France, then you would need to register as an entrepreneur, pay necessary taxes, etc. Web Developers are probably considered as *une profession liberale*, and the necessary steps can be undertaken through [the URSSAF site](https://www.autoentrepreneur.urssaf.fr/portail/accueil.html). (Registering as an autoentrepreneur would require holding long-term residence card.) Running such microentreprise is not very complicated, but there are a few pitfalls to avoid, and knowing French is certainly a necessity to deal with the administration.

If you are running your freelance business from abroad, then nothing prevents you from taking contracts with French clients. Such international collaborations are done all the time via freelancing sites (Again, there are quite a few sites for developers that require knowing French and being registered as an autoentrepreneur in France - they simply demand your SIREN number when registering.)

Answer (score 0):

You need nothing rather than securing payment by working only under the coverage of  secure freelancing platform such as upwork or freelancer. com.

You can also request the client to sign (employee and employer) legal e-signature contract, the well-known and fully legal one is hellosign.com

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes. Also, if the suggestion appears to be wrong, it may incriminate someone who follows the advise.